# How do I call an async function with method run_in_executor in Python/Tornado?

Tags: python, multithreading, tornado

I have a python file where I have a tornado request handler class with the following relevant code:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 20)
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy())

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   async def connect(self):
      # some code
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      await loop.run_in_executor(executor, self.connect_function)

   async def connect_function(self):
      #some code with an await operation somewhere here
```

So my main goal is to be able to use the request handler with threads. The way I found I could do this is with the method `run_in_executor`. The problem here is that in the `connect` method I want to await the end of `connect_function` which also is async, this usually raises an error: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MainHandler.connect_function' was never awaited` .
My questions are if is this the only way I can make threads work in this tornado request handler, and if so, if there's a way I can wait the execution of an async function with the method `run_in_executor`.

Comment: In addition to Ben's answer, remember that `run_in_executor` should be used for running blocking tasks in separate threads. Anything that can be done asynchronously should be done in the main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run async functions in a ThreadPoolExecutor (unless you also run another event loop there, which is not usually what you want). You could schedule a callback on the main event loop and then wait for it on the thread, but that's complex. As a general rule, when you're using an async framework like Tornado, you want to stay on the event loop thread as much as possible, and only send things out to a ThreadPoolExecutor when necessary (and then let those functions `return` to the main thread instead of trying to call back to async code from the thread).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in simple English.

Take [fetch_reference_fx](https://norman-lm-fung.medium.com/small-script-to-scan-reference-rates-using-ccxt-654418395080) (It's an async function) as example,

Instead of:

```
fetches = [
                    one_loop.run_in_executor(None, fetch_reference_fx, price_sources, vwap_num_levels, self.app_context.logger),
                ]
results = await asyncio.gather(*fetches)
```

Do this instead:

```
fetches = [
                    fetch_reference_fx(price_sources, vwap_num_levels, self.app_context.logger)
                ]
results = await asyncio.gather(*fetches)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

asynch handling has changed with version 6 I think.

So some examples / howtos might be misleading. You probably want to look the the tornado documentation page for the latest examples. Like [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html) scroll down for the asynch code examples